# How to replace comma and forward slash in input text field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Example: "1,23/456" should return "123456"

So when I type "1,23/456" in the input field and hit "enter" it should be changed to "123456".

```
<input id="Id" ng-model="Id" name="searchInput" type="text">
```

Comment: what's the input type? `number`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML  inputbox using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the type of the input is number then it will automatically reject the slash. However I have faced compatibility issues with number fields when testing with IE

So you can register an ng-change or ng-blur event callback on your input field and you can define the callback function like this

```js
$scope.onInputBlur = function(){
  //$scope.value is the model for your field
  $scope.value = $scope.value.replace(/,/,'','g'); // replace comma with empty string
  $scope.value = $scope.value.replace(/\//,'','g'); //replace slash with empty string
}
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input type="number" />` or sanitize the model value using a regular expression.

```js
console.log('1,23/456'.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
```